# How to call java method using Angular JS?

Tags: java, angularjs

I am using `Angular JS` with `Spring MVC` for my project. I want to call Java method directly from html using `Angular JS` to populate Drop Down.

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: You will be not able to call java method from AngularJs, what you can do is  enable a REST service for your java method from spring and invoke that REST call from your AngularJS

Comment: With Cordova, you can develop your own native Java code and call it from any javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You just can't because Angular JS is working on the client side while Java is most likely running on the server. What you need is a REST interface that accepts invocations from the Angular JS app. As the REST interface is (most likely) written in Java on the server side, you can then make the desired Java call to get the drop down values and send them back as response as part of the REST call. Use Angular JS then to interpret and use the response from the server.

Sorry for not being more precise but that should give you a pretty good starting point.